# IntelliJ Idea 10 is picking up old compiled classes. I cannot clean them

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJIdea 10.0.3 for a Grails application and all of a sudden when I run my app it picks up and old compiled class. I tried doing a grailsclean several times, and it appears to clean successfully. However, when I run the application and I access a known screen it still shows an old hard coded value that I no longer have anywhere in my application.
I also tried to do a Make and Rebuild the project, but not success either.

Anybody know how I can solve this without renaming the class?

Thanks a lot this is really frustrating and slowing me down tremendously.

Comment: Me and a collegue of mine have the same problem...

Comment: I had this issue and solved it by checking all of the possible compilation output folders and making sure they weren't being picked up. In my case, an old classes nested pretty deep down was overwriting the module compilation output in my artifact, and deleting the old folder fixed the issue. A silly issue, but it's worth remembering that IntelliJ is only going to clean output folders that you tell it to clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 10.5.1 update, it may fix this problem. If it doesn't, you can enable **clean output directory on rebuild** in `Settings | Compiler` and then rebuild again.

Contact support with the sample project and the steps to reproduce if you cannot resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for your response but that was already checked by default and the problem still happened.

Comment: Note: I am not having that problem any more it has been a while since I have been out of IntelliJ idea 10